# Java - substring issues

Tags: java, string, arraylist, substring

I'm going to show all of my code here so you guys get a gist of what I'm doing.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Plagiarism {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Plagiarism myPlag = new Plagiarism();

        if  (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: No files input");
        }
        else if (args.length > 0) {
            try {
                List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (args[i]));
                    foo = simplify(reader);
                        for (int j = 0; j < foo.size(); j++) {
                            System.out.print(foo.get(j));
                        }
                }

                int blockSize = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
                System.out.println(args[2]);
                // String line = foo.toString();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int k = 0; k < foo.size() - blockSize; k++) {
                    list.add(foo.toString().substring(k, k+blockSize));
                }
                System.out.println(list);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> simplify(BufferedReader input) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            myList.add(line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","").toLowerCase());
        }
        return myList;  
    }

}
```

This is the code that is using substring.

```
int blockSize = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);

//"foo" is an ArrayList<String> which I have to convert toString() to use substring().
String line = foo.toString();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int k = 0; k < line.length() - blockSize; k++) {
    list.add(line.substring(k, k+blockSize));
}

System.out.println(list);
```

When I specify blockSize as 4 in cmd this is the result:

```
[[, a, , ab, abc ]
```

the text file (standardised using my other code) is this:

```
abcdzaabcdd
```

so the result should be this:

```
[abcd, bcdz, cdza, ] etc.
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"foo" is an ArrayList which I have to convert toString() to use substring().` why do you convert your list to String just to do String-hackery afterwards?

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me. I just used fixed values `int blockSize = 4` and `String line = "123abcdz456aabcdd";`.

Comment: Are you sure you're reading the correct value of `args`?

Comment: @Pshemo the issue obviously lies in converting the arraylist to string then. i can't work it out. it should work in theory i think but wont.

Comment: Out of curiosity, print the value of `args[2]`, and give us output result.

Comment: It wont let me use substring() with arrayList @donfuxx thats why i'm converting to string.

Comment: @user3364788 Yes, that is obvious conclusion that problem lies on converting `foo` list to String, but to help you solve this problem we would need actual code showing how you are creating this list and example of input.

Comment: @AntonH it's printing out whatever i input. If i specify java Plagiarism (text file) (text file) 4, it will print out 4.

Comment: Are you coding in an IDE? I suggest running it with the debugger to make sure your `blocksize` and `line` variables are exactly as you expect them to be. If you're getting different values going into the `for-loop` you'll have whacky behavior we can't help with unless we get more details.

Comment: i've now added all my code. Take a look.. maybe i have to make the whole thing a string rather than arraylist? if so can you guys help out? cheers guys.

Comment: Why are you opening the files in a loop through `args`? Why not using `args[1]`, since program name is in args[0]?

Comment: @AnthonH... with all due respect this doesn't matter, I tried swapping these around but I get an arrayoutofbounds error so it's staying as it is.. this is not my question :)

Comment: @AntonH Also I'm opening two files so cannot just specify one element of args, but need them both.

Comment: @user3364788 Yes, sorry, I misread that you read only one file. However, since `foo` is an ArrayList, shouldn't you loop through it and analyse the Strings it contains? `for (String fooString : foo) { for (int k = 0; k < fooString.size() - blockSize; k++) {...} }`?

Comment: You said that `text file (standardised using my other code) is this:
abcdzaabcdd`. Is it possible that you are assuming that this value should be returned from `foo.toString()`?

Comment: Also, you realise that since `foo = simplify(reader);` will recreate the ArrayList, that only the second file will be analysed?

Comment: @AntonH no it doesnt do that because it's in a for loop. Also Anton your method doesnt work.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, thats correct.

Comment: @Pshemo It's why I suggested looping through `foo` to get to Strings it would contain.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you are mistaken. I assume that seeing result of `System.out.print(foo.get(j));` printing content of this list as one line make you think that `foo.toString()` will also create similar result, but unfortunately toString returns result in form `[element0, element1, element2, ...]`. Maybe consider returning `StringBuilder` instead of `List<String>` from `simplify` method where instead of `myList.add(...)` use `stringBuilder.append(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code showing how to improve a little your code. Main change is returning simplified string from `simplify` method instead of `List<String>` of simplified lines, which after converting it to string returned String in form

```
[value0, value1, value2, ...]
```

Now code returns String in form `value0value1value2`.

Another change is lowering indentation lever by removing unnecessary `else if` statement and braking control flow with `System.exit(0);` (you can also use `return;` here).

```
class Plagiarism {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //you are not using 'myPlag' anywhere, you can safely remove it
//      Plagiarism myPlag = new Plagiarism();

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: No files input");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String foo = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[i]));
            foo = simplify(reader);
            System.out.println(foo);
        }

        int blockSize = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
        System.out.println(args[2]);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int k = 0; k < foo.length() - blockSize; k++) {
            list.add(foo.toString().substring(k, k + blockSize));
        }
        System.out.println(list);

    }

    public static String simplify(BufferedReader input)
            throws IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that since the blocksize loop is after the BufferedReader loop, that you're in fact only going to be parsing the second file, totally ignoring the first?

Comment: @AntonH Lets solve one problem at a time. Let OP learn. For now I was focused on data types, not logic. I was hoping that OP will describe problem of only seeing result of handling second file (if that is really a problem), or maybe will leave a comment that there was such problem but (s)he managed to solve it by him/her self.

Comment: @Pshemo this is a brilliant answer, thank you. As listed above, yes there is an issue that it is in fact only doing the second file, and not doing all of it, it is missing off one of the blocks at the end. I can't work this out.. more particularly the latter problem.

Comment: @Pshemo - Fixed the problem that it's missing off the final block by adding " + 1 " to the loop. Still have the first problem though.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry for all the messages but it is all now fixed: I added the second for loop inside the first. Thanks again!!